Should I write an email to a Latino teacher working in the US in English or Spanish?
I found the website of a professor working in the US, and I'm studying some of the class notes and exercises he uploaded there for his students (they are a bit old, making reference of courses he taught in 2010). Some of the notes are missing though, and I wanted to write him an email asking if he still has them and if it was possible he could share them with me.
I read on his CV he studied his bachelor and even worked a few years in a Latin American country, and I'm almost certain his mother tongue is, as mine, Spanish. I don't know then if I can write my email in Spanish (which will be better for me, since my English is not the best), or if it would be inappropriate and I must stick to English. I don't want to sound cocky or fake writing in rusty English when we clearly could use our native language, but neither to come out as over-friendly or rude for assuming things.

I'm a professor fluent in both English and Spanish with relatives who natively speak each language and I have lived in latin America.  For me if I received an email like what you're mentioning, it wouldn't make any difference if it was in one language or the other.

I would consider writing the email in Spanish, getting a good machine translation into English (editing it a bit yourself if needed), and then sending an email with both. Personally, as an English speaker with access to good machine translation, these days I would rather receive an email from someone in their own native language than a doubtful translation into mine.

However you wrote your question here, your English seems fine (even looking at the original version).

What if his mother tongue is Portuguese? :)

(Responding to my own comment -- I wasn't paying attention to the quality of the English in your question when I wrote it. I was thinking about the hypothetical general-case situation in my head. I agree with the people saying your English is fine, and I didn't mean to imply otherwise, whoops.)

If this professor is working in the US, then English

If the lecture notes are in English, I would write your request in English as well. That way he can e.g. delegate the task by forwarding your email to someone in his group.
I work as a non-native speaker in an English speaking country, I only use my native language with other speakers of this language if a) I know them and my question can only be answered by them (e.g. "Are you planning on attending meeting X ?") or b) they work in a country that uses my language and my question relates to work they've published in said language.
The goal is to try to avoid them having to translate my email should other people need to be involved. If you are making a request, you should always try to minimise the work for the person you are making the request to.

If you really are sure that his native language is Spanish, then you can write in either Spanish or English; both would be equally acceptable.  Perhaps a middle ground would be to write the first email in English, but mention that you're also a Spanish speaker and offer to switch to Spanish in subsequent communication.
It also depends a lot on the culture of the particular language in question. For example, French people are quite proud of their language and will always speak French to each other. Chinese people also tend to speak Chinese whenever possible.  Germans, on the other hand, seem to be quite happy to speak English, and it's fairly common to see Germans talk to each other in English in academic environments. I'm not sure what the situation is with Spanish.
The other answer by Marianne013 mentions a reason to use English in case the professor wants to delegate the task to other members of his group. I respectfully disagree: email is private communication, and the standard assumption is that the email will be read by the owner of the email account.  Even if there is some task that comes up (e.g. like in your case, gathering lecture notes) that involves other people, the professor can very quickly write a new message to whomever needs to see it.

With respect to the last paragraph - there is a reason that my admin has full read/write permissions on my email - so they can immediately take care of various things that I would delegate to them anyway. Sure, national lab and not a university, but the point stands - email to me may not be read and acted on by me.

email is private communication, and the standard assumption is that the email will be read by the owner of the email account - I somewhat disagree with this comment if you mean "only read by the owner".  If the email is purely a professional/academic email, it's common to forward email requests to relevant people.  (Also my university can technically read any email sent to my work address if they want, though I doubt they do.)

I agree with @Kimball, I work at a university and the only emails that I would not forward to other people are marked "confidential and not for distribution" and typically concern budgets. I would expect my emails to be treated the same. Business here would grind to a halt if everyone had to ask for permission before e.g. getting the local expert's input on a query they received.

I would bet that "willingness to speak English" depends less on "cultural pride" and more on "English proficiency" as an explanatory variable. That would explain your anecdotal observation (because Germans are on average more proficient in English than the French or Chinese - see e.g. the EF EPI). Invoking language cultural traits sounds iffy to me (three natives of Montréal, Abidjian and Paris might all speak French, but they probably have little else in common).

@UJM Not to start a relatively pointless tangent in the comments, but Aqualone wrote "French people," which isn't the same as "French speakers," which is what you referred to. Not to endorse their second para (I don't know the academic language habits of any of these groups).

@UJM I think it's a combination of both factors.  In case of France, there certainly is a bit of a "cultural" aspect--the stereotype that the French don't like to speak English is not entirely baseless (I mean in general, not in academia). In the case of China (and similarly Japan, Korea, etc) low English proficiency is probably the bigger factor

In the case of Chinese, I would add: it is not so much "cultural pride", but there seems to be general agreement that it seems very weird for two Chinese people to be speaking to each other in English.  If the OP were Chinese instead of Spanish (-speaking), they most likely would not have even asked this question.  Of course, there is chicken-and-egg question here—probably the situation arise in the first place due to low English proficiency among Chinese speakers

Email should not be considered private. Security issues aside, for employees of government-run universities in the U.S., anything they do on their university computers or accounts is considered public and subject to FOIA requests.

The safest option is to use English.  The recipient is working in a US school; presumably the person's website is in English, the person teaches in English, and the person publishes in English.
Anything else requires more questionable presumptions on your part.  For example, sometimes people who have spent time working in a country never bother to learn the language of the country.  Or, maybe your presumption that Spanish is their native tongue is simply wrong.
So, to me it comes down to "how awkward would it be if I wrote a note in Spanish and got back an 'I don't speak Spanish' reply?"  I'd guess that 999 times out of 1,000, this would be no problem, and maybe even 900 times out of a thousand, the recipient might be tickled by your effort.  I can certainly imagine cases where getting a persons Native Tongue wrong could be perceived as insulting rather than awkward, though, so some care is indicated.

A Us person with latin-sonding name couls be second/third generation and not knowing spanish that well

Although there is nothing wrong with writing it in Spanish, it's probably best to write it in English, especially if English is the official language of your countries and you are both proficient in it. To start off all in Spanish may cause him to wonder if you doubt his English ability.
That said, there's nothing wrong with dropping in a Spanish sentence or two - perhaps referencing your possible common native language - to establish rapport. This can also be an invitation for him to use some Spanish in his reply if he wishes to.
Also, since you stated you are "almost certain" (but not certain) that his mother tongue is Spanish, it may be best not to rely on his understanding of Spanish in your communication.
Finally, your English ability is totally sufficient. Don't be too hard on yourself. When I read your post a second time I found a couple of small details I could pick at if I wanted to, but there's certainly nothing about your writing style that's difficult to understand. Be yourself - a person who has a command of their second language at a very high level. That will come across as genuine, in my opinion. Besides, nobody communicates perfectly 100% of the time, even in their native language.

Simply using Spanish equivalents to "Dear Dr X" and "Best wishes, Ameliebe" would likely be sufficient to indicate your willingness to communicate in Spanish, without creating any difficulties if the recipient prefers English.

I don't see anywhere in the question that OP says they also live in the US.  Has it been edited?

OP did not state where they live. I've updated the wording to assume they live in different countries. Hopefully everyone will be satisfied. But whether they live in different countries or the same country, the main idea remains the same.
